# Flash Class Giving Me and Import Error

Tags: flash

Here is the code I wrote. It is a flash class based upon a generic object.

```
package{

import flash.events
import flash.ui
import flash.Sprite; 
import flash.Sound; 

    public class SongPlayer extends Object {


    private var _song : Sound;

    private var _soundTrans : SoundTransform; 

    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , onEnter); 

        public function SongPlayer (_sound:Sound) : void {

        _song = _sound;

        var chan : SoundChannel = new SoundChannel(); 

        chan = _song.play(); 

        };


    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

In fact, your code is full of errors:

- All (!) of your import statements are invalid. Check the API documentation for each class to find out the correct package or qualified class name to import (such as `flash.display.Sprite` and `flash.events.Event`).
- You add an event listener outside of a function block
- You did not even declare an `onEnter` function to handle the event
- There is no need to write `extends Object`, since all custom classes in Flash extend Object by definition.

For the future: Read the error messages. They usually mean something.  Then, over and over, fix only the first error, then recompile - until the compilation completes.

I am also quite certain that there are a lot of examples for playing sounds, even in the ActionScript API documentation, that you can use to get started - there is no need to do this from scratch...